# Parse an unserialized JSON object array with commas in values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, bootstrap-tags-input

I am using tag inputs to submit a string representation of 0 or more objects. The `input` value in the form is a comma separated list of stringified JSON objects.

Example:

```js
var value = "{}, {}, {}, {}"
```

Each of the individual objects have a field containing a name: `{..., name: "Doe, John"}`

Because this comma is here I cannot execute `JSON.parse(value)`

> Unexpected token , in JSON at position ...

I want to avoid doing any string split methods because of undesired splitting of names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add brackets to the string and it will parse correctly

```js
var value = "{}, {}, {}, {}, {}"
JSON.parse("[" + value + "]")
```